# R data - Changing my data frame (converting columns into rows and vice versa)

Tags: r, rows

So I have created a data frame in R with this output called 'data'

But I want to convert my data frame to something like the one below

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You can transpose using `t(data)`. But what is the reason for transposing? Because what you get back is matrix and not data frame.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To transpose in R use the function `t()`:

`t(data)`

Answer (score 4):

`t(data)` returns a `matrix`.

To convert it to a `data.frame` from the `matrix, wrap the output with`as.data.frame()`.

Answer (score 0):

`t(data)` returns list. If you want to shape your data, you can turn into data frame by coercion: `as.data.frame(data)`

Better solution: use `melt` function from `dplyr` package. It can easily turn your data into tabular form, then you can "effectively" play with your data.